# Hide Horizontal Scrollbar from TListView

Tags: delphi

I am facing a strange problem when removing the *horizontal scrollbar* from **TListView**.

```
procedure TForm1.listDataResize(Sender: TObject);
begin
    ShowScrollBar(listData.Handle, SB_HORZ, False);
end;
```

When using down or up arrow keys, then **Column** header Second and beyond is erased, when i resize the **column** manually then it is displayed back. When i remove the code from **listDataResize** then this problem no more occurs.

I just want to remove the *horizontal scroll-bar* from appearing in the **ListView**. As above code is working fine, the only thing bothering me is why second and beyond column headers are erased.

Comment: Have you checked if the columns have become width=0? When removing the scroll bar you also leave the component without a means to show all it's contents. The component might go back to a very basic view because there is less space to draw upon

Comment: rows are displaying ok. only the column header look like they are erased. even if i drag another window over the listview everything becomes ok. Just like painting issue. But i can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why it was happening, I deleted the current form holding **TListView** and created a new **Form** not touched any property of the form except **Caption** of the form and dropped the **TListView** once again.

```
ListView.RePaint;
ListView.Refresh;
```

Now it is no-more erasing the column header. I have not touched any property like double buffering etc. Working good.